# Eclipse Luna ant editor gives error when I add includeAntRuntime attribute

Tags: eclipse, ant

I'm running eclipse luna (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1), Build id: 20150109-0600).

When the compile target runs, it gives me a warning about missing the includeAntRuntime attribute.  So I added the attribute setting it to false as the ant documentation suggests.  The editor underlines the whole target element in red and says the includeAntRuntime attribute is unexpected.

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" includeAntRuntime="false" >
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build.classes}" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
</target>
```

I figured out that eclipse is using ant 1.9.2 whereas I'm using ant 1.9.4.  I changed the Ant home to point to 1.9.4 using Window>Preferences>Ant>Runtime dialog.

I restarted eclipse and its made no difference.  I'm still getting the same warning.  How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 1):

`includeAntRuntime` is an attribute of the `javac` task not `target`:

```xml
<target name="compile" depends="init" >
    <javac includeAntRuntime="false" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build.classes}" classpathref="compile.classpath"/>
</target>
```